# How to demonstrate that there would exist a vertex with degree less than 5? (Cross-check working)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, solution-verification, planar-graphs

Referring to a past question of mine that can be found here:

[How to demonstrate that there would exist a vertex with degree less than $ 5$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3952977/how-to-demonstrate-that-there-would-exist-a-vertex-with-degree-less-than-5/3952996#3952996)

This is the work that I have come up with following the guidance kindly provided by other members.

**Working:**

$$\text{Assume that every vertex of the graph have a degree of at least six.}\\
\text{ Using} ∑_{v∈V}deg(v)=2e \text{ for all graphs,}\\
\text{Since } deg(v)≥6 \text{ for all } v∈V \text{ according to the assumption, we have }\\ 2e=∑_{v∈V}deg(v)≥6n \\ \text{would imply } e \geq 3n \\ \text{ yet, according to Euler's theorem } e \leq 3n -6 \\ \text{therefore implying that there is a contradiction.}\\ \text{Now, it can be concluded that the initial assumption cannot be true, and S has at least one vertex with a degree at most five}$$

I was wondering if anyone would be wiling to check my work and provide any correction/advice on how to improve it?

My main issue is that I do not know if this working would be detailed enough.

I do not know if this is allowed on the site.

If not, just let me know and I will delete the question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks good, but you should clarify at the very end that the contradiction implies that the assumption is false (as you say), thus there is at **at least one vertex with degree $\leq 5$**. Also be careful, this result is for having some vertex having degree $\leq 5$, not $<5$.